# svn2git migration with part of tags and branches

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tags, svn2git

We have an old SVN repo with 30 000 revisions.
It contains a projectX with 3 branches with the names branchA, branchB, branchC

The 3 branches exist since revision 20 000.

The setup of our repo is as followed:

```
https://server/repo/projectX/

branches/
changes/
projects/
releases/
tags/
```

The branches contain BranchA, branchB and branchC and tags contains a lot of tags. As you can see there is no trunk.

Now we want to migrate all the data (without old branches, tags etc) from the beginning till revision 20 000. and from 20 000 we want to migrate till the end with tags and branches and a trunk (the branchA branch).

This is what I want to do with [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git).

```
# svn2git https://server/repo/ProjectX --notrunk --nobranches --notags --revision 0:20000 --metadata

# svn2git https://server/repo/ProjectX --trunk branches/branchA --branches branches --tags tags --revision 22545:HEAD --metadata
```

Will this give a right result or is it not done to change the trunk (will maybe mix it up) during an svn2git migration and should I keep `--notrunk` and decide in git what will be my master? Other input is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The `svn2git` tool you use is based on `git-svn`.

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist.

You can also easily in one run create individual Git repositories for different projects in the same SVN root.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the `svn2git` you used) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)